# How to read *.log file using QTP?

Tags: logging, qtp

I have to write automatic test verifying correctness of server logs. How can I do this using QTP. Those log files are very long so it takes a lot of time to do this line after line.

Format of the lines in log file is as follows:

```
2012-01-04 14:26:08,832|DEBUG|company.project.algorithm.core.AlgorithmCore - No primary operation was found.
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Verify that the logs have valid or that there are no errors messages in this run of the application.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't clarified your question so I'll give answers to two possible questions.

- Starting with QTP 11 there is an option to listen to an applications log messages via the **Log Tracking** feature (available in the *Test Settings*), for applications using a log4X (log4j, log4net etc) logging framework.
- If all you want to do is verify that a valid log was created you need to parse the log file, this has nothing to do with QTP directly. You can either do it in plain VBScript and run it from a test or you can do it in another language (.NET or COM) and call it from the test (e.g. by using QTP's `DotNetFactory`).